# Empty trash from external hard drive

Tags: finder, hard-drive, catalina, trash

When my external hard drive got disconnected (without ejecting), it created a `.Trashes` folder. Now, I'm not able to delete the folder by emptying the trash. I keep on getting `The operation can’t be completed because the item “MyFolder” is in use.` error. How do I delete this folder as it is occupying a huge amount of space on my hard disk? TIA.

I'm using MacOs Catalina Version 10.15.1 (Macbook Air).

**EDIT #1**

I've tried to delete the directory using `sudo rm -rf /Volumes/MYDRIVE/.Trashes/` command and got `rm: /Volumes/MYDRIVE/.Trashes/: Operation not permitted` error.

Comment: Did you try giving Terminal [full disk access](http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/)?

Comment: @lx07, I've tried giving full disk access to my terminal and now I'm getting `rm: .Trashes/: Directory not empty` error. However, I don't find any files inside it.

Comment: Try some of the answers here : [“Directory not empty” sudo rm -r -i “file name” not working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116217/directory-not-empty-sudo-rm-r-i-file-name-not-working?rq=1)